# 2D image rotation about 3D vector and projection

Tags: image, rotation

I'm trying to rotate a 2D image such that the viewing angle is not along the normal to the 2D plane, but along some other vector.

I tried various things such as:

```
img = Import["ExampleData/lena.tif"];
theta=Pi/4; n={1,0,0};
r = RotationMatrix[theta, n];
ImagePerspectiveTransformation[img, r, PlotRange -> All]
```

which I expected to be a rotation about the x axis (effectively narrowing the image), but it doesn't do that.

I don't want any foreshortening in the image (i.e. should be viewed at infinity).

Sounds simple but I'm stumped!

edit: theta and n are in the general case not nice, tidy things e.g. theta=0.378, n={9.55067, 0.418879, -2.17293}

I also need to project a 2D image onto an arbitrary plane (which is not the same as changing the viewing angle). Is there a way to do this cleanly?

Comment: `ImageCrop[ImageTransformation[img, {2 #[[1]], #[[2]]} &], 
 ImageDimensions@img {1/2, 1}, Right]`?

Comment: Thanks, but how can I automatically pick the parameters for an arbitrary rotation vector and rotation angle? My example was perhaps too simple.

Comment: But that one is a geometry problem, unrelated to Mathematica!

Comment: Well I find myself all too often doing things in Mathematica 'the hard way' when I'm *sure* there's an inbuilt function to do the job efficiently. Doing it 'the hard way' here means do geometry, then rotate, then stretch, then rotate again. I just feel like I'm banging rocks together, here.